# What are my options to talk to someone with an IPhone in Vietnam?

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, instant-messaging

My brothers-in-law are going to Vietnam for a medical emergency.  One of them has an Iphone and will have access to wifi.  He has to pay something like $2 a minute to call me when he gets there to keep us updated, so we're seeking less expensive communication alternatives.  What are some of his options for sending us messages, calling, etc. from his phone when connected to wifi?

Comment: Off-topic, not really related to computer hardware or software.

Answer (score 2):

[Skype for iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8) allows free Skype-to-Skype calls, and Skype-to-phone calls are relatively inexpensive as well.